# sfdx force:lightning:lwc:test:run not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lwc-jest

I have written a bunch of tests for LWC. I'm trying to run it using `sfdx force:lightning:lwc:test:run` but I run into:

> ERROR running force:lightning:lwc:test:run:  No lwc-jest executable
>   found. Verify it is properly installed. Run "sfdx
>   force:lightning:lwc:test:setup --help" for installation details.

I tried to install `lwc-jest` using [@salesforce/lwc-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@salesforce/lwc-jest) looks like it's been deprecated and has been renamed to `@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest`.

Does this mean `sfdx force:lightning:lwc:test:run` is referencing an older module (@salesforce/lwc-jest)?

Is there a way to fix this/what am I missing here?

Note: I'm able to run tests using `npm run test:unit`.

**Edit:**

I tried installing jest using `sfdx force:lightning:lwc:test:setup` and ran into the below issue:

> ERROR running force:lightning:lwc:test:setup:  npm command not found.
>   Verify npm is properly installed and try again.

I have installed jest using:

```
npm install
npm install @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest --save-dev
```

**NPM version - 6.4.1**

**NPM Path - C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules**

**Node Version - v10.15.1**

**OS - Windows**

Comment: Please mention the operating system and node version you have as it works fine on MACOSX.

Comment: I agree with @MohithShrivastava, to me, it seems that npm is not on the default path of your OS. That is why `sfdx force:lightning:lwc:test:setup` has failed.

Comment: @MohithShrivastava NPM version  6.4.1 and OS windows. I updated my question as well.

Comment: What about node version and also what’s your default npm path?

Comment: Hi @MohithShrivastava I have added that to the question now.

Comment: Try by installing npm with global flag and see if it makes difference

Comment: Ugh! Unfortunately facing the same issue. @MohithShrivastava

Comment: I ran into the same issue as you with the `lwc:test:setup` command on 2 different Windows PCs. I just used npm to install sfdx-lwc-jest and then `sfdx-lwc-jest` to run tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty much spot on with your investigation and finding that `lwc-jest` has been deprecated in favor of `sfdx-lwc-jest`. The SFDX plugin was in fact referencing the deprecated binary.

This has just been fixed in the plugin by this [PR](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-plugin-lwc-test/pull/17) and should be released into the main SFDX CLI via a patch release in a week or two.

Comment: Thank you! @trevorBliss

Answer (score 6):

npm i @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest

This should do the trick

Comment: This worked for me. Ran into the same error as the original question even with latest versions of node and npm

Answer (score 0):

Either try to install using `sfdx force:lightning:lwc:test:setup` or if you are trying to use npm directly, you can install [sfdx-lwc-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest) instead of lwc-jest, see the page you [referred](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@salesforce/lwc-jest):

> This package, @salesforce/lwc-jest, has been renamed to @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest. Please update your projects to reference @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest. @salesforce/lwc-jest will continue to be updated through the Winter '20 release, then development and releases will only happen against @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest.

Comment: I have updated my question. @jeferson chaves

Comment: Hey, @d_k: have you removed the previous module `lwc-jest`?

Comment: Yes, I have removed the `lwc-jest` module.